# How to return the generated image by phpThumb and not the original one with code appended?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, imagemagick, thumbnails, phpthumb

I'm generating images through phpThumb on my Wordpress based website using Magic Fields 2 but I'm having problems posting those images to We Heart It and other websites since they don't recognize it as an image due to all the code appended.

Therefore I was wondering if there's a way to make phpThumb return the actual generated image thumbnail link instead of the original link with all the code appended like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/basetheme/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/files_mf/1331856830IMG_0286.jpg&w=364&h=200&zc=1&q=95
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ailoo.net/2008/07/wordpress-plugin-autothumb-phpthumb/ <-- I'm using this plugin for the same! :)